# Powershell Test-Path returns false, but the file exists

Tags: powershell

My script should look for a file in a computer list (txt) and return true if the file exists and false if it doesn't.

The problem is, it's returning "False" even though the file DOES exist.

```
    $computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\SvcHosts\PSKILL_SvcHosts_Workstations.txt

foreach ($comp in $computers)
{
    Test-Path \\$comp\c$\Windows\myfolder\myapp.exe
}
```

When I run `Test-Path \\COMPUTERNAME\c$\Windows\myfolder\myapp.exe` alone it returns true as it should.
When I run from the txt list, returns false when it shouldn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wrong credentials for that file?

Comment: Add a `Write-Debug` of `$comp` and the complete path inside the loop and enable debug output: probably don't quite have what you expect in the file.

Comment: Try escaping the `$` with a `

Comment: I'd use `-LiteralPath` and double quotes around the path, just to be on the safe side. If `$comp` is a name rather than an IP address, make sure that it can be resolved. Also, note that `C$` is an administrative share, so you need admin privileges on `$comp` to be able to access it.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds strange, but I just ran my script (without change it) in another machine and it worked as expected.
The main difference between the two machines I tested the script is the version of PowerShell ISE.

Machine 1
**ISE Version: 3.0**
Test-Path returns false even if the file exists

Machine 2:
**ISE Version:2.0**  Test-Path works fine.

Not sure if these versions have difference betweeen them about access or something. I have the impression that it returned false in Machine 1 because the script couldn't reach the computer (I was running it under admin privileges anyway).

I know it doesn't make much sense...but anyway, case closed.
Many thanks to everyone that helped.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was terribly confused why my script fails in ISE but works in a console.

Answer (score 0):

Use a formatting string to fill in the values:

```
$Computers | ForEach-Object { 
    Test-Path ('\\{0}\c$\Windows\myfolder\myapp.exe' -f $_) 
}
```